# what is wrong with my if condition despite the condition is met?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Why the if statement not working despite the two conditions are met?

Code:

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
// Only change code below this line
for(var i =0; i < contacts.length; i++){
    if(prop === contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) && name === contacts[i][prop]){
        return contacts[i][prop];
    }else {
        return "Not working";
    }
}


// Only change code above this line
}

lookUpProfile("Harry", "firstName");
```

Comment: `contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)` returns a boolean. How is it supposed to be equal to a property name?

Answer (score 2):

You exit in the first loop with either the name or with `"Not working"`.

To prevent this, move the return value `"Not working"` outside of the loop, at then of all looping.

A direct comparison of the value with the property is enough. You need to return the object, instead of just the known name.

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
    // Only change code below this line
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (name === contacts[i][prop]) {
            return contacts[i];
        }
    }
    return "Not working";
    // Only change code above this line
}

lookUpProfile("Harry", "firstName");
```

Comment: `prop === contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)` does not make sense at all. It is comparing a string to a boolean.

Comment: goddammit you are right. although is tarted learning js  5 days ago but this mistake is stupid!.
thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead and fix the if contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)  is a boolean.

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){

  for(var i =0; i < contacts.length; i++){
    if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) && name === contacts[i][prop]){
        return contacts[i][prop];
    }
  }
  return "Not working";
}
console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "firstName"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)` only returns boolean values (True or False). Therefore when you call `prop === contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)` it will always return false, since `"firstName !== true"`.

So you might fix it with  `if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) && name === contacts[i][prop]){...}`

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors, the first is the wrong use of the `hasOwnProperty` which returns a bool value (true or false). [More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

The other error is that the loop returns after the first entry, to prevent this put the `return "Not working"` line after the loop finished.

I've made a working example:

```js
var contacts = [
   {
      "firstName":"Akira",
      "lastName":"Laine",
      "number":"0543236543",
      "likes":[
         "Pizza",
         "Coding",
         "Brownie Points"
      ]
   },
   {
      "firstName":"Harry",
      "lastName":"Potter",
      "number":"0994372684",
      "likes":[
         "Hogwarts",
         "Magic",
         "Hagrid"
      ]
   },
   {
      "firstName":"Sherlock",
      "lastName":"Holmes",
      "number":"0487345643",
      "likes":[
         "Intriguing Cases",
         "Violin"
      ]
   },
   {
      "firstName":"Kristian",
      "lastName":"Vos",
      "number":"unknown",
      "likes":[
         "JavaScript",
         "Gaming",
         "Foxes"
      ]
   }
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) && name === contacts[i][prop]) {
      return contacts[i][prop];
    }
  }
  return "Not working";
  // Only change code above this line
}

let res = lookUpProfile("Harry", "firstName");
console.log(res);
```